# Azure blob storage to JSON in azure function using SDK

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I am trying to create a timer trigger azure function that takes data from blob, aggregates it, and puts the aggregates in a cosmosDB. I previously tried using the bindings in azure functions to use blob as input, which I was informed was incorrect (see this thread: [Azure functions python no value for named parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437077/azure-functions-python-no-value-for-named-parameter)).

I am now using the SDK and am running into the following problem:

```
import sys, os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myenv/Lib/site-packages')))
import json
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService 

data = BlockBlobService(account_name='accountname', account_key='accountkey')
container_name = ('container')
generator = data.list_blobs(container_name)

for blob in generator:
print("{}".format(blob.name))
json = json.loads(data.get_blob_to_text('container', open(blob.name)))


df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json)
print(df)
```

This results in an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.json'
```

I realize this might be an absolute path issue, but im not sure how that works with azure storage. Any ideas on how to circumvent this?

---

Made it "work" by doing the following:

```
for blob in generator:
loader = data.get_blob_to_text('kvaedevdystreamanablob',blob.name,if_modified_since=delta)
json = json.loads(loader.content)
```

This works for ONE json file, i.e I only had one in storage, but when more are added I get this error:

```
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 21907 (char 21906)
```

This happens even if i add `if_modified_since` as to only take in one blob. Will update if I figure something out. Help always welcome.

---

Another update: My data is coming in through stream analytics, and then down to the blob. I have selected that the data should come in as arrays, this is why the error is occurring. When the stream is terminated, the blob doesnt immediately append `]` to the EOF line in json, thus the json file isnt valid. Will try now with using line-by-line in stream analytics instead of array.

Comment: Why do you need `open` around `blob.name`?

Comment: If I leave it out I get the error `azure.common.AzureMissingResourceHttpError: The specified blob does not exist.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>BlobNotFound</Code><Message>The specified blob does not exist`. With open added it at least sees that there is a file there. Cant post the full traceback, but in the same traceback: `No handlers could be found for logger "azure.storage.common.storageclient"`

Comment: Have you tried logging the blob url?  After you've worked out the url you're requesting in your code, use storage explorer to compare what you are requesting with your code with what's actually in the storage account: this is the blob storage equivalent of "File not found".

Comment: Thanks for comment. I found out what was causing the initial problem, see above updates. Thanks.

Comment: @Nord112, can you post an answer if every thing work now ??

Comment: @Thomas, sadly with line by line processing I run into the `Extra data` issue. Since stream analytics JSON files aren't technically valid (no top or bottom delineation of where the file ends). So I need to find a way to make the function read through each line in each file and append to a dict. Will post answer if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. In the end it was a quite simple fix:

I had to make sure each json entry in the blob was less than 1024 characters, or it would create a new line, thus making reading lines problematic.

The code that iterates through each blob file, reads and adds to a list is a follows:

```
data = BlockBlobService(account_name='accname', account_key='key')
generator = data.list_blobs('collection')

dataloaded = []
for blob in generator:
loader = data.get_blob_to_text('collection',blob.name)
trackerstatusobjects = loader.content.split('\n')
for trackerstatusobject in trackerstatusobjects:
    dataloaded.append(json.loads(trackerstatusobject))
```

From this you can add to a dataframe and do what ever you want :) 
Hope this helps if someone stumbles upon a similar problem.